# laravel how to get related data from another table with no relation

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on laravel and i have the following table structure

elments table

```
+----+--------------+------------+--------+
| id |  element     |   category | cities |
+----+--------------+------------+--------+
|  1 |  element 1   |     1      | 1,2,3  |
|  2 |  element 2   |     2      | 2,3    |
+----+-----------+---------------+--------+
```

cities table

```
+----+-----------+
| id |  city     |  
+----+-----------+
|  1 |  city 1   |
|  2 |  city 2   | 
|  3 |  city 3   |  
+----+-----------+
```

categories table

```
    +----+-------------+
    | id |  category   |  
    +----+-------------+
    |  1 |  category 1 |
    |  2 |  category 2 | 
    |  3 |  category 3 |  
    +----+-------------+
```

I use the eloquent query with relations as following

```
$elements =Element::with('categories')->get();
```

but how to get cities names for each elements from the cities table in the same query

Comment: Do not store `1,2,3` in `cities`; you should have a `pivot` table for `element_city`, with `element_id` and `city_id`. Then you can define a `many-to-many`, and do `Element::with(['cities', 'categories'])->get()`. For your current approach, you'll need to loop over each `$element`, then do a separate query for `City::whereIn($element->cities)->get()`, which is super inefficient. Please normalize your database and read the documentation on how a `many-to-many` works in Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: yes i understand your replay and i know about it but i am looking if there is  a way for current approach

Comment: *"from the cities table **in the same query**"* - If you want to get all of the cities in the same query, then you need to refactor like I've said. There isn't a way to define a relationship based on a CSV value in `cities`.